# BigInteger Parse Octal String?

Tags: c#, biginteger, octal

In Java, I could do

```
//Parsing Octal String
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("16304103460644701340432043410021040424210140423204",8);
```

Then format it as I pleased

```
b.toString(2); //2 for binary
b.toString(10); //10 for decimal
b.toString(16); //16 for hexadecimal
```

C#'s `BigInteger` offers the formatting capabilities shown above but I can't seem to find a way to parse BIIIG (greater than 64 bit, unsigned) Octal values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but if performance is not a priority, you can construct the `BigInteger` manually:

```
string s = "16304103460644701340432043410021040424210140423204";
BigInteger bi = s.Aggregate(new BigInteger(), (b, c) => b * 8 + c - '0');
```

The above solution also works for any base not greater than 10; just replace the `8` in the above code with your required base.

**Edit**: For hexadecimal numbers, you should use the `Parse` method. Prepend with `0` if your number should be interpreted as positive even if its first character is `8`–`F`.

```
string s = "0F20051C5E45F4FD68F8E58905A133BCA";
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's going on. Would there be a simple way to add implementation for hex? (to parse big hex strings)

Comment: @BackpackOnHead why would you add an implementation for hex when you can use the built-in Parse method?  It's very unlikely that you'll improve over Microsoft's implementation.

Comment: @phoog - I asked this then I jumped into bed for a bit and facepalmed, haha.

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation for hex (and all bases up to 16); expand it by adding characters to the string constant (credit where credit is due; this is based on Douglas's answer):

```
private const string digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private readonly Dictionary<char, BigInteger> values
    = digits.ToDictionary(c => c, c => (BigInteger)digits.IndexOf(c));
public BigInteger ParseBigInteger(string value, BigInteger baseOfValue)
{
    return value.Aggregate(
        new BigInteger,
        (current, digit) => current * baseOfValue + values[digit]);
}
```

It is likely that arithmetic where one operand is an int is faster than if both operands are BigInteger.  In that case:

```
private readonly Dictionary<char, int> values
    = digits.ToDictionary(c => c, c => digits.IndexOf(c));
public BigInteger ParseBigInteger(string value, int baseOfValue)
{
    return value.Aggregate(
        new BigInteger,
        (current, digit) => current * baseOfValue + values[digit]);
}
```

Comment: +1: That's the way I would have extended it for non-hexadecimal bases greater than 10 too.